# Adding XMP Meta Data in Postscript

Tags: pdf, postscript, xmp

I am adding XMP meta data in Postscript file but facing problem in Coverting it into PDF using Adobe Distiller.

Here is my PS File

```
/MainFont
/Helvetica-Bold findfont 15 scalefont def

/SloganFont
/Helvetica-Oblique findfont 7 scalefont def

/OwnerFont
/Helvetica findfont 10 scalefont def

/CardOutline
{ newpath
90 90 moveto
0 144 rlineto
252 0 rlineto
0 -144 rlineto
closepath
.5 setlinewidth
stroke } def


/doBorder
{
99 99 moveto
0 126 rlineto
234 0 rlineto
0 -126 rlineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
stroke
} def

/Diamond
{
newpath
207 216 moveto
36 -54 rlineto
-36 -54 rlineto
-36 54 rlineto
closepath
.8 setgray fill
} def

/doText
{
0 setgray 105 200 moveto
MainFont setfont
(Diamond Cafe) show

105 188 moveto
SloganFont setfont
("The Club of Lonely Hearts") show
265 126 moveto
OwnerFont setfont
(Sam Spade) show
270 111 moveto
(Owner) show


}def


CardOutline
doBorder

doText
Diamond
showpage

/Creator (FrameMaker 6.0)
/CreationDate (D:20020214144924)
/ModDate (D:20020215142701)
/Author(John Doe)
/Title (Processing XMP Data in EPS Files)
/Subject (XMP)
/Keywords (XMP, pdfmark)
/DOCINFO pdfmark
```

At the end of this postscript file i attached XMP Meta data so i am desiring that when this post-script produces PDF it will show meta data in XMP.

Comment: You say you have a problem but forgot to mention what it is.

Comment: See chapter 5 of the [XMP specification](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xmp/sdk/XMPspecification.pdf).

Comment: @Jongware i said i am desiring so that means m facing problem in output

Comment: @lhf i read it but did'nt get it because m new to PS.

Comment: If you want help , you';re going to have to tell people **precisely** what you are doing, and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pdfmark needs a mark before the data so add `[` before `/Creator`.

Comment: i did that but i am not sure how to do it right kindly provide me the ps file here thanks